# Error with install.packages() for R on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: r, bash, ubuntu-16.04

I recently installed R on Ubuntu 16.04 and tried installing a package that I need:

```
install.packages('gimme')
```

The dependencies seem to download fine but their installation is where the errors pop.  Even tho g++ is installed for example, R can't seem to use it:

```
* installing *source* package ‘nloptr’ ...
** package ‘nloptr’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
checking for g++... no
checking for c++... no
checking for gpp... gpp
checking whether the C++ compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/tmp/Rtmpq1Yg7t/R.INSTALLedf3b8432e7/nloptr':
configure: error: C++ compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘nloptr’
* removing ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/nloptr’
```

From what I can tell it looks like R can't find the compilers on my system, but I can't seem to find out how to fix this.  I installed the package on a windows machine just fine.

Any experience setting up and installing R packages on Ubuntu?

Comment: Do you have `g++` installed? (That's a ubuntu package, nothing to do with R.) If not, `apt-get install g++` is a good start; anything more and I suggest you redirect your research to topics not related to R, such as "ubuntu install g++".

Comment: You can get the `gcc` and `g++` with `apt-get install build-essential`. https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/build-essential

Comment: I have gcc and g++, r just isn't recognizing it.

Comment: You might also see if installing `r-base-dev` helps; i.e., from the command line run `sudo apt install r-base-dev`.

Comment: I installed r-base-dev.  But can't seem to install any additional packages through R.

Comment: Both @duckmayr and Anoboymous coward are correct as `r-base-dev` implies the `build-essential` package -- in short you should _never_ be in a situation where `g++` does not work.

Comment: yea i'm not sure what sequence of events led to `g++` not working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
apt-get install --reinstall g++
```

made all the difference. was missing the --reinstall flag